What are, by classical definition, the weakly connected components of this graph?
I've been working on some network science (a kind of applied graph theory field) exercises, and I've found a difference in definitions for weakly connected components.
Take this graph, which has the strongly connected components [10, 11, 12, 13] (not reachable by other nodes), [9,8,7] (not reachable by other nodes), [14, 15, 16] (other nodes are not reachable from them), and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

List of edges: [(1,2), (2,1), (3,1), (2,3), (3,6), (6,3), (5,3), (3,4), (3,15), (7,3), (4,5), (5,16), (10,5), (6,14), (7,8), (9,7), (8,9), (10,11), (12,10), (11,12), (13,11), (12,13), (13,12), (14,15), (16,14), (15,16), (16,15)].
Based on Wikipedia, weak components are partitions into total orders based on reachability. I'm not very familiar with order theory definitions, but as I understand partitions are disjoint - this confuses me e.g. for this example, as there seem to be multiple possible solutions based on which of the first two strongly connected component we include in the biggest weakly connected component (cannot include both, cannot reach e.g. 9 from 10 and vica versa): 

either [14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and [10,11,12,13];
or [14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13] and [7,8,9] are the weakly
connected components

if I understand the definition correctly. (I
was thinking that if sets need not to be disjoint and should be
"maximal", we'd have the two larger weakly connected components from
the possibilities.)
The network science definition (which I less prefer) defines weak connectivity based on whether nodes are connected if edge directions are ignored (i.e. if the network would be undirected). That would result in one big weakly connected component.
Out of curiosity I ran some simple graph analysis tools (NetworkX in Python) and those seem to use this definition.
Am I misunderstanding the Wikipedia definition, if so, what would be the weakly connected components in this example? Are the two definitions equivalent?

The definition by Graham, Knuth, and Motzkin given on Wikipedia is not equivalent to the standard definition (by which the entire graph is weakly connected, since its underlying undirected graph is connected). Almost everyone who talks about weak components is talking about components of the underlying graph, as far as I know, but I will stick to the Graham, Knuth, and Motzkin definition in the remainder of this answer.
Wikipedia's one-line summary of the definition - "a partition of the vertices of the graph into subsets that are totally ordered by reachability"  - is confusing, because it suggests "reachability is a total order on the elements of each subset", but actually means "reachability is a total order on the subsets". That is, for any two parts $U, V$ of the partition, either all vertices of $U$ are reachable from all vertices of $V$, or vice versa, but not both.
In general, the partition into weak components is going to be coarser than the partition into strong components. In the example graph, we can start with the strong components $A = \{1,\dots,6\}$, $B = \{7,8,9\}$, $C = \{10, \dots, 13\}$, and $D = \{14,15,16\}$. Of these, $B$ and $C$ can both reach $A$ and $D$, but not each other; $A$ can also reach $D$.
Therefore by the $\parallel$ relation as defined on Wikipedia ($u \parallel v$ if $u$ cannot reach $v$ and $v$ cannot reach $u$), we have $b \parallel c$ for all $b \in B$ and $c \in C$, so we combine those two strong components. Since $\parallel$ does not hold for any other pairs of strong components, our final partition has three parts: $A$, $B \cup C$, and $D$.
These three parts are totally ordered by reachability: $B \cup C$ can reach both $A$ and $D$, and $A$ can reach $D$. We have found the finest such partition, because for any two vertices $u,v$ in the same part, one of two problems would occur if we separated them:

either $u \Leftrightarrow v$ (both vertices are reachable from each other), so if $u$ and $v$ are in different parts, reachability on the parts would not be an asymmetric relation;
or $u \parallel v$, so if $u$ and $v$ are in different parts, reachability on the parts would not be total.

